# Performance - Android Studio lags problems

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio, lag

There is something bizarre that happens when my app lags. When the app lags, the speed of my chars is slowed.

I don't mean it is moving in few frames, but the actual speed is lower.

For example, when I don't have lag on my app, the player can jump 10 blocks, but with lag it jumps only 4.

This would mean it skips some lines of code when the game lags, which can't be true. The code is pretty big, so I can't really post it and I don't think it is relevant for now. Any advice? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: What do you mean lag ? First of all where are you testing your game ? On emulator (which one Android Default or Genymotion). How it is connected with android studio. it is just IDE.  
Please add some more details about your problem.

Comment: My phone is connected with android studio, if this is what you need to know. (via usb)

Answer (score 0):

This could be possible if you tied your game logic to your frame rate. Need for Speed Rivals for instance did this and set the frames per second cap to 30 in the game. If you changed it via (it was either command line instruction or ini file change) to 60, then the game would play at 2x speed. and be unplayable (other than comically)

So if your logic is tied to your Frames per second, and you drop frames, then entire loops of your logic 'could' be 'skipped' (not actually skipped, but unexpected behavior visually on the next game loop(s)'

Comment: The problem is that the game logic is not tied to the frame rate. I use Libgdx, but still it doesn't make sense at all. Any advice?

Comment: Without any code... no, sorry... Though I would recommending using a lot of logging (logcat or SLF4J/Logback which is very nice on android once you learn it) and specifically log the places where your 'jump' method is, see what the input to the method is. (and then if you can 'make' it lag and see what the inputs to that method are then, then you can start to track down if it is actually messing with values)

Comment: Another thing to check is to see if your "physics" logic is solid, such as the 'gravity' that "pulls down" the character after they jump.(This will obviously depend on 'specifics' of how you implemented your game logic.so I can only give 'generalities' like this, but those two places is where I would start logging first)